# Ввести последовательность целых чисел не используя массивы,циклы и указатели

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть предположение, что данное задание нужно делать с помощью рекурсии, правда без указателей я не понимаю как это сделать.

**Входные данные:** последовательность целых чисел.

**Выходные:** элементы последовательности бОльшие, чем среднее значение последовательности и сумму всех эл-ов последовательности.

Comment: Как определяется, сколько чисел в последовательности? Известно заранее или как?

Comment: @Harry пользователь сам выбирает количество вводимых эл-ов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот, [примерно так](https://ideone.com/fyqrHT) -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double inout(int sum = 0, int count = 0)
{
    int i;
    double avg;
    if (cin >> i)
    {
        sum += i;
        ++count;
        avg = inout(sum,count);
        if (i >= avg)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
        avg = double(sum)/count;
    }
    return avg;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    inout();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ввод прекращается, если вводим не число.

Comment: Всё работает замечательно,благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Сейчас разобрал программу,только не понял(не судите строго студента-раздолбая),почему ввод прекращается именно при вводе нечислового эл-та?

Comment: Потому что при этом `cin>>i`, который возвращает поток `cin`, преобразуется в `false` - так как поток при попытке читать не число как число, переходит в состояние `fail`.

Comment: теперь понял всё и снова спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можете завести 1) текущее количество введённых чисел; 2) текущую сумму чисел.

Далее вызываете функцию, которая 1) читает следующее число; 2) добавляет число к сумме; 3) добавляем +1 к количеству введённых; 4) вызывает саму себя, если количество введённых не равно нужному количеству

Comment: По сути я похожий алгоритм и предполагал,но проблема стояла в реализации. Мне уже помогли,но и вам спасибо за предложенный вариант.